# Simple neural network fails to make correct predictions. Where did I make a mistake?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to build a simple neural network, with 3 inputs, 3 outputs, and no deep layer, that will perform a gradient descent to tweak its weights, and be able to transform input array into the output array. For some reason it doesn't work (predictions stop changing after a few iterations), and I can't seem to figure out why. Can you help me out?

Similar code worked when I had 1 input and 3 outputs, or 3 outputs and 1 input. I used to calculate derivatives like so: `derivatives = inputs * pure_error`. But now that I need to do that for the matrix of weights, I'm using `derivatives = np.outer(inputs, pure_errors)`, that's the only change I have made.

**The code:**

```
import numpy as np 

inputs = np.array([3, 5, 1])
weights = np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.05],
                    [1.0,0.53,0.5],
                    [1.7,2.3,1.2]])
target_predictions = np.array([1.5, 10, 93])
learning_rate = 0.05

def ann(inputs, weights):
    predictions = np.dot(weights, inputs)
    return predictions

# Initial Predictions
predictions = ann(inputs, weights)
errors = (predictions - target_predictions) ** 2
print("Predictions:",predictions, "Errors:",errors)

for i in range(350):
    predictions = ann(inputs, weights)
    errors = (predictions - target_predictions) ** 2

    print("Predictions:",predictions, "Error:",errors)

    pure_errors = predictions - target_predictions
    derivatives = np.outer(inputs, pure_errors)
    weight_updates = derivatives * learning_rate

    weights -= weight_updates
```

**Output:**

```
Predictions: [ 1.35  6.15 17.8 ] Error: [2.25000e-02 1.48225e+01 5.65504e+03]
Predictions: [15.585 29.875 22.545] Error: [ 198.387225  395.015625 4963.907025]
Predictions: [ 4.90875 12.08125 18.98625] Error: [1.16195766e+01 4.33160156e+00 5.47803519e+03]
.......
Predictions: [ 9.48428571 19.70714286 20.51142857] Error: [  63.74881837   94.22862245 5254.59298776]
Predictions: [ 9.48428571 19.70714286 20.51142857] Error: [  63.74881837   94.22862245 5254.59298776]
Predictions: [ 9.48428571 19.70714286 20.51142857] Error: [  63.74881837   94.22862245 5254.59298776]
```

Comment: You have 3 inputs of of size 1, so you will need only one weight and one bias.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. Instead of:

```
derivatives = np.outer(inputs, pure_errors)
```

I needed to do:

```
derivatives = np.outer(pure_errors, inputs)
```

Passing the variables in wrong order changed the results somehow swapping the numbers and updating the wrong weights.